# Parsing multiple JSON objects

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON data from a weather API and get result JSON data printed to the console but I am having trouble accessing the data inside the multiple objects.

Im not sure if I should be doing structs for wind,atmosphere, condition or for speed, humidity, text, and temp

JSON Data:

```
    {
   "location":{
      "woeid": 2502265,
      "city":"Sunnyvale",
      "region":" CA",
      "country":"United States",
      "lat":37.371609,
      "long":-122.038254,
      "timezone_id":"America/Los_Angeles"
   },
   "current_observation":{
      "wind":{
         "chill":59,
         "direction":165,
         "speed":8.7
      },
      "atmosphere":{
         "humidity":76,
         "visibility":10,
         "pressure":29.68
      },
      "astronomy":{
         "sunrise":"7:23 am",
         "sunset":"5:7 pm"
      },
      "condition":{
         "text":"Scattered Showers",
         "code":39,
         "temperature":60
      },
      "pubDate":1546992000
   },
   "forecasts":[
      {
         "day":"Tue",
         "date":1546934400,
         "low":52,
         "high":61,
         "text":"Rain",
         "code":12
      },
      {
         "day":"Wed",
         "date":1547020800,
         "low":51,
         "high":62,
         "text":"Scattered Showers",
         "code":39
      },
      {
         "day":"Thu",
         "date":1547107200,
         "low":46,
         "high":60,
         "text":"Mostly Cloudy",
         "code":28
      },
      {
         "day":"Fri",
         "date":1547193600,
         "low":48,
         "high":61,
         "text":"Showers",
         "code":11
      },
      {
         "day":"Sat",
         "date":1547280000,
         "low":47,
         "high":62,
         "text":"Rain",
         "code":12
      },
      {
         "day":"Sun",
         "date":1547366400,
         "low":48,
         "high":58,
         "text":"Rain",
         "code":12
      },
      {
         "day":"Mon",
         "date":1547452800,
         "low":47,
         "high":58,
         "text":"Rain",
         "code":12
      },
      {
         "day":"Tue",
         "date":1547539200,
         "low":46,
         "high":59,
         "text":"Scattered Showers",
         "code":39
      },
      {
         "day":"Wed",
         "date":1547625600,
         "low":49,
         "high":56,
         "text":"Rain",
         "code":12
      },
      {
         "day":"Thu",
         "date":1547712000,
         "low":49,
         "high":59,
         "text":"Scattered Showers",
         "code":39
      }
   ]
}
```

---

```
class ForecastClass : Codable {
    var windSpeed : Int
    var humidity : Int
    var temperature : Int
    var text : String

        init(_ windSpeed: Int, _ humidity: Int, _ temperature: Int, _ text: String) {
            self.windSpeed = windSpeed
            self.humidity = humidity
            self.temperature = temperature
            self.text = text
        }
    }
```

//----------------------------\

```
struct Forecast : Codable {
    let windSpeed : Int
    let humidity : Int
    let temperature : Int
    let text : String
}
struct WeatherStruct : Codable{
    let weather : [Forecast]
}
```

Get weather function with API

```
func getWeather() {
        YahooWeatherAPI.shared.weather(lat: "37.372", lon: "-122.038", failure: { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print("Error pulling weather data")
        }, success: { (response) in
            let data = response.data
            let forecastInfo = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
            print(forecastInfo!)
        }, responseFormat: .json, unit: .imperial)
    }
```

Comment: Your sample JSON is invalid. Could you check it. Also, your question is not clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Please show real JSON data, not some debugger/print output. That said, pasting JSON into app.quicktype.io gives a very reasonable first version of the structs and parsing code you need.

Comment: This is not JSON, this is the `forecastInfo` dump. Yes, rather than `JSONSerialization` use structs and `Codable`. And you cannot mix scopes, for example `humidity` and `temperature` are in different scopes and `windSpeed` doesn't exist.

Comment: I just updated the sample JSON. Basically I am trying to populate the struct with the JSON data but I am not sure the best way/ how to access the different elements inside the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
struct Weather: Codable {
    let location: Location
    let currentObservation: CurrentObservation
    let forecasts: [Forecast]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case location
        case currentObservation = "current_observation"
        case forecasts
    }
}

struct CurrentObservation: Codable {
    let wind: Wind
    let atmosphere: Atmosphere
    let astronomy: Astronomy
    let condition: Condition
    let pubDate: Int
}

struct Astronomy: Codable {
    let sunrise, sunset: String
}

struct Atmosphere: Codable {
    let humidity, visibility: Int
    let pressure: Double
}

struct Condition: Codable {
    let text: String
    let code, temperature: Int
}

struct Wind: Codable {
    let chill, direction: Int
    let speed: Double
}

// MARK: - Forecast
struct Forecast: Codable {
    let day: String
    let date, low, high: Int
    let text: String
    let code: Int
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let woeid: Int
    let city, region, country: String
    let lat, long: Double
    let timezoneID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case woeid, city, region, country, lat, long
        case timezoneID = "timezone_id"
    }
}


do {
  let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: data)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```